# CSS for side menu height won't change when theme file is edited

Tags: javascript, css, magento, themes

This is my [website](http://rupshop.com). It is built with Magento. I want to reduce the left side menu height from 463px to 400px. I tested via Firebug to change the value in the theme-pink.css file. But after editing, when I save the value and open the file again its still unchanged. Did it use any JavaScript script for validating or something else? If so, how can I change this? Please suggest a better option.

```
.cms-index-index .header-v0 .ver-megamenu-header .sm_megamenu_wrapper_vertical_menu {
  display: block;
  min-height: 463px;
```

Comment: Did you change the  min-height: 463px; to  min-height: 400px;

Comment: Yep i did but it won't change the value. After saving the file and open the file and found same value before. I searched on google and found that problem is for owership but can't figured out its solution.

Comment: Sorry but I can't see the change has been saved in the file. I am adding it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to solve this. If you want to set the height of your menu-container I would recommend that you change the current max-min height to 400px or remove max-min height add a "height:400px;" property. If no changes occurs you can try clearing cached files and reload, if nothing still changes try adding "height:400px !important;" to override conflicting properties.
And if that doesn't help the conflict is probably the result of something else.

/S

Answer (score 0):

I checked the website and found:

**file:theme-pink.css
Line number: 3740**

```
/*= HEADER STYLE 2 =*/
.cms-index-index .header-v0 .ver-megamenu-header .sm_megamenu_wrapper_vertical_menu {
  display: block;
  min-height: 463px;
}
```

That means you didn't save the file. And if you saved it you forgot to upload it in server. Or, you changed a copy of the css file. Not the original one. Please make sure your changes are taking effect by adding the style:

```
body {
 background-color: red !important;
}
```

in css file. You should see the change in website.

[image: Check changes]

And if you are suspecting some JS changing the value, JS will be normally adding the style attribute to the element like,

```
<div class="css_effect sm_megame..." ... style="min-height: 463px;">..</div>
```

which is also not the case here.

Please cross check and I am sure we've missed something.

Comment: It's might cause for some cpanel restriction i guess. I deleted the file and upload the new one but still same file appear on file manager. Cpanel don't allow to edit or delete any file from directory.

Comment: oh. what happens if you delete the file and not uploading new file? Site goes blank?

Comment: Oh. Well, if you find the answer post it out here. So that other people could get help.

Comment: Yep Finally find the Solution. In the Backend Less Compiler was on , so every time compile the code to default one.